# Help please with tag [self-guided]

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wiki-excerpts

Because new tags may be added at any time and enquiring into them is tedious without SEDE (which is only run weekly and seems not fully in sync even so) it is difficult to be sure, but [self-guided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided) may at present be the only tag on the main Travel site without a Usage guide of sorts.

As an adjective it does not, in my opinion, make a good tag. [self-guided-tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided-tour) may be more suitable. However that is not quite how the tag is in use at present for four Open questions (and two Closed):

Q: [Are there self-guided tours in Boston/Harvard?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/are-there-self-guided-tours-in-boston-harvard)

Q: [Self Guided Northern Lights Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/self-guided-northern-lights-tour)

Q: [How to find people to do long hikes?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67498/how-to-find-people-to-do-long-hikes)

Q: [How can I travel to the “Eye of the Sahara”? Are there tours? Can I self-guide?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/how-can-i-travel-to-the-eye-of-the-sahara-are-there-tours-can-i-self-guide)

[tour-guides](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tour-guides) is a synonym of [guides](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guides) so an alternative might be to retag the four with [tours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tours), but the Usage guide for that is:

> Organized tours as opposed to travelling or seeing things on your own. See also the "guides" tag.

thus would then have to be rewritten.

There is, IMO, justification for something like [self-guided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided) but a sensible Usage guide might be easier for [self-guided-tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided-tour).

1. Should [self-guided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided) be burninated?
2. If not, should [self-guided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-guided) be renamed, and if so what to?
3. What would be an appropriate Usage guide for whichever tag is chosen, if one is?

Comment: I agree that self-guided does not sound like a good tag, but changing it to self-guided-tour seems also a little bit inappropriate, since as you point out, there are other self-guided things one can do. The best I could come up with was self-guided-travel, but that is also not that great.

Comment: I agree with @RoflcoptrException here. It's not a great tag, but renaming it may not be beneficial either. Wouldn't a good description fix the problem? If it stays without usage guide, I'm all for removing the tag entirely. No point in keeping ambiguous tags around, tags are for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. No
3. How about:

> For questions about independently visiting locations for which an organized tour us the most common option.